# Pass for public transport in San Francisco

Tags: buses, san-francisco

Is there a full day pass available for buses in San Francisco?

I know about MUNI passes but do they include just cable cars or buses also?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the day passes include all of Muni buses, from [TripAdvisor](http://www.tripadvisor.com/Travel-g60713-c139263/San-Francisco:California:Muni.Passes.For.Visitors.html):

> Muni offers 1, 3, and 7 day "Visitor Passports" which allow the user to ride **all forms of Muni transportation**, including the cable cars, the modern and historic (F-line) streetcars, **the various diesel and electric (trolley) buses** for a single flat rate and from [SFMTA](http://www.sfmta.com/getting-around/transit/fares-passes/visitor-day-passes):
>
> A Visitor Passport can be purchased for 1, 3, or 7 consecutive days of unlimited **rides on Muni, Muni Metro, historic streetcars, and cable cars**.  Single ride cable car tickets are also available.

Sources: [SFMTA](http://www.sfmta.com/getting-around/transit/fares-passes/visitor-day-passes), [TripAdvisor](http://www.tripadvisor.com/Travel-g60713-c139263/San-Francisco:California:Muni.Passes.For.Visitors.html)

Comment: Thanks for guidance. Does this include buses too?i am sorry am bit confused. It includes bus, cable cars, f-line street cars?

Comment: @404 as the answer suggests, yes.

Comment: What's interesting is that if you do not want to use cable cars at all, it is WAY cheaper to pay each bus trip, as a 90-minute ticket is worth 2.25$ and a day pass is worth 17$ (more than 6 times 90 minute tickets, i.e. 9 hours just riding buses/light rail). You can get a Clipper card in many convenience stores to avoid carrying change all the time.

Comment: Can i use that 2.25$ bus ticket multiple times?within 90-minutes?Or it is just for one trip?

Comment: The $2.25 bus ticket ($0.75 for youth and senior citizens) is a 90-minute ticket good for as many MUNI vehicles as you can manage. MUNI is somewhat unusual in that it runs: diesel bus, trolley coach (electric bus with overhead wires), cable car (unique, of course), historic streetcar, and a convertible streetcar that runs as a subway in downtown and a streetcar at street level. They must need a lot of different mechanics. If you pay cash, you either get a paper transfer from the driver or a printed receipt from a machine, depending what mode of transport. Your expiration time is printed there.

Comment: Let me also mention that the "Clipper Card" is valid on other transit providers, in particular BART from SFO, and saves the hassle of exact change. Available at SFO, many retailers, and several BART stations.